# SQL: Select same attribute for two different columns pointing to same foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables one reference table and one transaction table
eg: Reference table:

```
PersonID CITY
   1      A
   2      A
   3      B
   4      C
```

Transaction table:

```
PersonA   PersonB  Relation
   1         3        23
   2         3        35
   1         4        46
   3         4        53
```

PersonID in reference table is the foreign key for PersonA and PersonB in the transaction table.

What would I like to get is:

```
CityPersonA   CityPersonB  RelationSum
    A              B            58
    A              C            46
    B              C            53
```

Is there a way we can do it through SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two `JOIN`s and one `GROUP BY`

```
 select a.city, b.city, sum(t.relation)
 from reference a
 join transaction t on t.personA = a.personID
 join reference b on t.personB = b.personID
 group by a.city, b.city
```